# Parsing nested span tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull company information from the following website:

http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/markets/stocks/summary/?q=T-T

I see from there page source that there are nested span statements like:

```
<li class="clearfix">
<span class="label">Low</span>
<span class="giw-a-t-sc-data">36.39</span>
</li>
<li class="clearfix">
<span class="label">Bid<span class="giw-a-t-sc-bidSize smallsize">x0</span></span>
<span class="giw-a-t-sc-data">36.88</span>
</li>
```

The code I wrote will grab (Low, 36.69) without problem.  I have spent hours reading this forum and others trying to get bs4 to also break out (Bid, 36.88).  The problem is, Bid comes out as "None" because of the nested span tags.

I am an old "c" programmer (GNU Cygwin) and this python, Beautifulsoup stuff is new to me.  I love it though, awesome potential for interesting and time saving scripts.

Can anyone help with this question, I hope I have posed it well enough.
Please keep it simple because I am definitely a newbie.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside: I'm pretty sure there are APIs you can use to get stock prices.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Hi, I am not just looking for prices, that would be easy.  I am looking at some of the ratios published and building the tool myself will allow flexibility to do other stuff.  Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from a website, I recommend PyQuery (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery). Just as BeautifulSoup it uses lxml for fast XML/HTML-parsing and you can access the HTML-elements jQuery-like selectors.

```
import pyquery
root = pyquery.PyQuery("http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/markets/stocks/summary/?q=T-T") # you can also pass the HTML-source, that you want to parse
spanlist = root("li.clearfix > span")
for span in spanlist: print span.text
```

**Output:**

```
Open
36.45
Previous Close
36.28
High
37.36
Low
36.39
Bid
36.88
```

(Just the first ten lines of output, but I think you get my point: few lines, great result...)

### Almost the same with BeautifulSoup4

```
>>> import bs4
>>> text = "<li ..." # HTML-source-code from Question
>>> root = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> [ span.text for span in root("li.clearfix > span") ]
[u'Low', u'36.39', u'Bidx0', u'36.88']
```

And now structured:

```
>>> [ ( span.text, span.findNextSibling('span').text) for span in root.select("li.clearfix > span.label") ]
[(u'Low', u'36.39'), (u'Bidx0', u'36.88')]
```

Print in separate columns:

```
>>> for span in root.select("li.clearfix > span.label"):
>>>    print "%s\t%s" % ( span.text, span.findNextSibling('span').text )
Low 36.39
Bidx0   36.88
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post.  I have downloaded pyquery and it imports properly.  I will give it a try.  I do have some reservations about your suggestion only in as much as, everyone seems to stick to what they know.  I assume these results could be produced in beautifulsoup, beautifulstonesoup, lxml also.  I really need to learn a language, any language and I think there would be a few recommendations as to what I should learn.  Is pyquery just a different parser add-on to python?  I am still very interested in seeing how you would do this in bs4.

Comment: I have to admit, BeautifulSoup looks more pythonic to me. I check, if there is a similar way in BeautifulSoup4 to achieve a similar result. My first guess was PyQuery, because it uses CSS-selectors and as those developed over the years, so I think it is a very powerful tool. And yes: PyQuery is just another parser-module (or I might say another API for the lxml-parser-module as I understand it).

Comment: Hi, sorry to bug you, but can you include the code that puts these into separate columns "Dimension" and "Measure".  Sorry, I really don't know what I am doing well enough.  It takes me so long to figure out the most basic things I can do in C.

Comment: Ok, I think that's it: Using BeautifulSoup4, structured in tuples... should I rearrange my Answer, so that the BS4-Part is at the beginning and my PyQuery alternative at the end?

Comment: Wow, thanks, I will learn a lot from dissecting this, after spending so much time floundering.  Really appreciate your help.  You rock!

Comment: Ahm, so, what do think about rewarding my answer by _voting my answer up_ or _accepting_ it _as best answer_??

Comment: I added some if statements when writing out the CSV which took care of the Bid, Ask problem. Still trying to figure out how to resolve the problem with "Top 1000 Ranking".

Answer (score 0):

So it is working way, way better than I had it working, but there are still some issues.  I am posting the full script so you can see what I am up to.  I will spend some time and effort investigating the issues, but this will help me learn python and beautifulsoup better anyway.

```
"""
This program imports a list of stock ticker symbols from "ca_stocks.txt"
It then goes to the Globe website and gets current company stock data
It then writes this data to a file to a CSV file in the form

index, ticker, date&time, dimension, measure

"""

import urllib2
import csv, os
import datetime 
import re #regular expressions library
import bs4
#from bs4 import BeautifulStoneSoup as bss
#from time import gmtime, strftime
#from lxml import etree
import pyquery

#import dataextract as tde

os.chdir('D:\\02 - \\003 INVESTMENTS\\Yahoo Finance Data')


symbolfile = open('ca_stocks2.txt')
symbolslist = symbolfile.read().split('\n')


def pairs(l,n):
# l = list
# n = number
    return zip(*[l[i::n] for i in range(n)])

def main():
    i=0
    while i<len(symbolslist):
        print symbolslist[i]

        url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/markets/stocks/summary/?q=" +symbolslist[i])

        root = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url)
        [span.text for span in root("li.clearfix > span")]
        [(span.text, span.findNextSibling('span').text) for span in root.select("li.clearfix > span.label")]

        dims = [[]] *40
        mess = [[]] *40
        j=0
        for span in root.select("li.clearfix > span.label"):
            #print "%s\t%s" % ( span.text, span.findNextSibling('span').text)
            dims[j] = span.text
            mess[j] = span.findNextSibling('span').text
            j+=1

        nowtime = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

        with open('globecdndata.csv','ab') as f:
            fw = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
            for s in range(0,37):
                csvRow = s, symbolslist[i], nowtime, dims[s], mess[s]
                print csvRow
                fw.writerow(csvRow)    
        f.close()

        i+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I know this is ugly code, but hey, I am learning.  The output to CSV looks like this now:

(4, 'T-T', '2013-11-09T19:32:32.416000', u'Bidx0', u'36.88')

(5, 'T-T', '2013-11-09T19:32:32.416000', u'Askx0', u'36.93')

(6, 'T-T', '2013-11-09T19:32:32.416000', u'52-week High05/22', u'37.94')

The date, "05/22" would change every time the price breaks out to a new high or low.  This is not ideal for the name of a dimension (field).

(7, 'T-T', '2013-11-09T19:32:32.416000', u'52-week Low06/27', u'29.52')

(35, 'T-T', '2013-11-09T19:32:32.416000', u'Top 1000 Ranking:', u'Profit: 28Revenue: 34Assets: 36')

For some reason, it has lumped these dimensions (fields) and measures (data) all together.  Hmm...

This is a list of some of the problems.  But, like I said, I should be able to figure this out now.  Learn a lot, thanks.  Having someone that knows what they are doing, provide some input is awesome.